# How do I get my old WhatsApp account on my new phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, lost-phone

I lost my old phone yesterday and it had my WhatsApp account on it. Today I bought my new phone and I was wondering how I could get my account back. I have both my the number for the account and the WhatsApp code for that account also.

How can I get my account back?

Comment: Have you seen [Migrate whatsapp from phone (old expired number) to another one?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/69983/16575) Does that apply to your situation? I guess you told your provider to "expire the old device" (as you consider it lost), so it should fit.

Answer (score 2):

As referred in the [Whatsapp FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/general/24460358):

> In the unfortunate case that your phone gets lost or stolen, we can
>   help make sure that no one can use your WhatsApp account.
>
> As soon as possible you should call your mobile provider to lock your
>   SIM card. Then, it will not be possible to verify the account on that
>   phone again as you need to be able to receive SMS or phone calls to
>   verify an account.
>
> After you have locked the SIM in your stolen phone, you can use a new
>   SIM with the same number to activate WhatsApp on your new phone. This
>   is the fastest way to deactivate your account on the stolen phone.
>   WhatsApp can only be activated with one phone number on one device at
>   a time.
>
> If you are not ready to activate WhatsApp on a new phone with the same
>   number we can deactivate your account. Email us with your phone number
>   in the full international format as described here. Please note that
>   we are not able to help you locate your phone. Remote WhatsApp
>   deactivation from another device is not possible.
>
> Important: Even with the SIM card locked and phone service disabled,
>   WhatsApp can be used on Wi-Fi if you do not contact us with an account
>   deactivation request.
>
> More important details about deactivated accounts:
>
> When your account is deactivated, it is not completely deleted. While
>   your account is deactivated:
>  Your name is still on your contacts'
>   Favorites / Select Contact lists.
>  Your contacts can send you messages,
>   which will remain in a pending state for up to 30 days. 
>  If you
>   reactivate your account before it is deleted, you will receive any
>   pending messages on your new phone and you will still be in all of
>   your group chats. 
>  If a deactivated account is not re-activated within
>   30 days, it will be completely deleted.
>  Note: Since your chat history
>   is stored on your device, we cannot retrieve your previous messages.