# Migrating WhatsApp to new phone and new number

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.2-jelly-bean, whatsapp-messenger

So, this is my scenario:

Phone A (Old phone):
Handles WCDMA sim only. Old number is in this phone and whatsapp is associated to this number. I have the number and the phone. Number is still active. Has Android Jellybean

Phone B (New phone):
Handles microSIM only. New number is on this phone. Has Android KitKat.

I want to migrate my WhatsAPP account from my old phone to the new one! Only problem is, I can't insert old sim in the new phone or the new sim in the old one because they are different types (WCDMA and microSIM).

So how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Just to make this clear. Your both SIM cards are probably GSM and WCDMA has nothing to do with CDMA. WCDMA is a synonym for 3G network connectivity.

Comment: Related: [Migrate whatsapp from phone (old expired number) to another one?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/69983/16575)

Answer (score 0):

WCDMA is related to network type and micro SIM is related to size of SIM card. You can trim or cut the previous one to micro size and use it in the latest phone. Transfer of account can also be done with in WhatsApp (if you wish to).
*** [Tutorial for cutting the SIM](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-cut-your-own-micro-sim-card/)