# Move WhatsApp account without SIM

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My problem is exactly the one described in [Migrate whatsapp from phone (old expired number) to another one?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69983/migrate-whatsapp-from-phone-old-expired-number-to-another-one).

I want to move my WhatsApp account from my old phone to a new one, but the SIM of the old phone is already expired (nonetheless, I currently can use my WhatsApp in it). In my case, what I want is to continue using that WhatsApp account on my new phone. I don't care about the chat history or contacts (I already save them).

So, I have read that in a rooted phone, by accessing the `/storage/Android/data` and copying the `com.whatsapp` folder and replacing it in the same directory of the new phone, the account can be moved and no verification number is needed. I have noticed that even with a non-rooted phone, I can access those folders, copy them, and replace them, as in the instruction, but in my case, it did not work.

Is there are differences in the content of, for instance `com.whatsapp` folder, when you access in rooted mode and non-rooted mode? If not, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is most probably because the Whatsapp version is different. If it is the same it works ( I have done it in past). But next problem in line what will you do if the expired SIM number is allotted to somebody else by your telecom carrier??

Comment: I have checked it, and the both phones I have the same version of whatsapp. My phones are not rooted. About the carrier, that is not my concern at this moment, but I am aware of it.

Comment: Did you reboot the phone?

Comment: Yes, I did. I still ask me to introduce a number to make the verification. What folder did you have inside your `com.whatsapp` folder?

Comment: Folders are same on my rooted and non - rooted device. As long as you copied all, this may not be the problem.Another thing to try. Uninstall Whatsapp on new phone but let the data be there. Install whatsapp and *WhatsApp will automatically find your backup and ask you if you would like to restore it* - restore it

Comment: I uninstalled and then installed it again, nothing happened, actually the `com.whatsapp` was erased. Then I copy the one from my old phone again, and still nothing happen. My `com.whatsapp` folder is around 15MB and contains two folders one is called `cache` which contains single files and a folder called `SSLSessionCache`, and the second one is called `files` and is empty.

Comment: In order to successfully copy the data from one phone to another in the way you described, you need to actually fix the permissions and SELinux contexts of the files. An app like TitaniumBackup will do that for you, so I recommend an app like that.

Comment: @GiantTree, what permissions are you referring to? and my phone is not rooted and I am not willing to root it (at least not the new one ), and to my understanding titanium is for rooted devices.

Comment: You should first migrate your account to the new number using the `Change Number feature`: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/27585377/?category=5245246

Comment: @BurNor I am talking about file permissions and the file owners. If an app can't access a file (because it is owned by another user, like `adb`), it might resort to deleting it and creating a new one with the correct owner (an app can delete files in a directory it owns). You are right, Titanium Backup is for rooted phones. Maybe `adb` has the needed privileges to change the owner and the SELinux context of files. If both phones are not-too-old Samsung ones, you can use the data migration wizard to transfer the data to your new phone without having to deal with these issues.

Comment: @GiantTree, just to mention that both phones are Xiaomi, the old one has a android version of 4.4.4, and the new one 6.01. I really dont know how to overcome this, I thought (and it seems to work for other users) that just by copying the so called `com.whatsapp` from one phone to another, and then reboot the phone, it should work, but in my case it did not.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is very possible, but your methods will never work. Firstly, you got have to know that there are two different `com.whatsapp` folders. The one you were just talking about is so useless that anyone on any device can access it.

You need the whole directory from `root/data/data/com.whatsapp`. To copy this, you need root permissions right, and to copy them in a new device you need root as well so that you are able to put them in the root dir.

Answer (score 1):

If you can root your device, then transferring your WhatsApp account would be an easy task.

Use Migrate to backup your WhatsApp data from your old device and restore it to your new device. But both phones must have root access.